# I am unable to find fault in my algorithm trying to solve spoj stavatar

Tags: algorithm

I'm trying to solve spoj question stavatar http://www.spoj.com/problems/STAVATAR/.
I have tried all test cases generated random ones but still wa.
I am unable to find flaw in my algorithm.

```
#include<cstring>
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdio>
using namespace std;

char a[1000010],b[1000010];
int d[1000010];

int main()
{
    int n;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    scanf("%s",a);
    scanf("%s",b);
    int k;
    scanf("%d",&k);
    for(int i=0;i<k;i++)
    {
        int x,y;
        scanf("%d %d",&x,&y);
        ++d[x],++d[y+1];
    }
    long long sum=0;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        sum+=d[i];
        if(sum%2!=0)
        {
            char t;
            t=a[i];
            a[i]=b[i];
            b[i]=t;
        }
    }
    printf("%s\n",a);
    printf("%s\n",b);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pay attention to `Constraints`, specifically the last part :
[image]

You might note the part in the end:

> '....\t\r\x0b\0c'

These are the white-space printable characters.

Now, coming back to your solution. We can see you input the strings using [scanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/), which will read till the first whitespace it encounters, which could be any on `'\t', '\x0b', '\x0c'`. But in this specific question, a string should terminate only at `'\n'` character.

For example :
If the string is :

> `ab\tcd`

which will look like

> `ab    cd`

in a CLI. The question demands that the first string be `ab    cd`, whereas, you are taking `ab` as first string and `cd` as the second.
I guess, you understand the reason of this solution getting a WA.

Also, You might find [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/) function helpful.

**Edit :-**
One could also use `scanf` function in this way - `scanf("%[^\n]s", string);` to perform the same task.

Comment: Knew about the getline function but was stupid to not see constraints properly.Thank you AC now